# How to detect system halt and recover last status in C#?

Tags: c#

I making a editor like program in Windows with C#.

I wonder that how the programs restore their working status or last working file that wasn't saved by user. The Photoshop and the 3Ds Max show a dialog to restore user's last working after system halt such as plugged out or bluescreen.

How do they do it? Do they just save their status every seconds? That's so simple and reasonable but not fancy. Is this only the way?

Comment: Yes, they just write a temporary file every minute or so (often a user-configurable period). They persist the name of the temporary file somewhere like the registry, and delete the file (and persisited name) when the file is closed as a result of the user exiting the program normally, or closing the file explicitly.

Comment: http://office-recovery.com/word.asp

Comment: There's not facy thing, though. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an unhandled exception handler and inside it save the current data to a special file.

Check [AppDomain Unhandled Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Application DispatcherUnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want to protect yourself from other kind of issues like system errors then you need to save periodically the information

Comment: This exception should not work when system halt but really useful to make a program's crash reporter.